# simplest way to find the factor between two position vectors relate to another vector direction

Tags: vector, 3d, perspective

[image: picture 1]

Given arbitrary a and b unit vectors defining positions A and B, what's the simplest way to know the factor (relative position) on the line defined by A and B (being A 0.0 and B 1.0) where another unit vector direction intersects the line??

At the moment I'm intersecting both lines (AB, third vector) and the projecting that into AB and dividing by it's length' to the the "gradient value" which works. But I feel like there must be a cheaper way using the directions of all vectors.

Let me know if there's such.

I'm also wondering if I'm doing this right overall, since while I'm geeting the image on the left I think I would want the one on the right:
[image: picture 2]

Thanks